# Grunt nunjucks-2-html

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, nunjucks

I'm trying to compile my templates via grunt nunjucks-2-html:

this is my simplified grunt file:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

grunt.initConfig({
      nunjucks: {
          options: {
              data: {},
              paths: '/templates/'
          },
          render: {
              files: [
                  {
                      expand: true,
                      src: '*.html',
                      cwd: '/templates',
                      dest: 'build',
                      ext: '.html'

                  }
              ]
          }
      }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-nunjucks-2-html');
};
```

my folder structure looks like this:

````
```
project
│   Gruntfile.js
│
└───templates
│      index.html
│      foo.html
│  
└───build

```
````

When i run grunt nunjucks i got the following error:

**"Running "nunjucks:render" (nunjucks) task  No files specified."**
So obviously nunjucks can't find my templates. 
I have no idea where to config the template path, to me my gruntfile seems valid. If you have any idea, I would be glad.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `__dirname` variable references the directory the Gruntfile lives in.

You could try using `paths: __dirname + '/templates/'` or just simply `paths: 'templates'` as described in the [nunjucks-2-html npm documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-nunjucks-2-html#usage-examples).